# Import xlsx file into SAS from static url link

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS but used to working in python.

In python, I can read an xlsx file from a static Box.com link by calling pandas read excel function on the Box link.

```
pd.read_excel("https://box.com/shared/static/<url>.xlsx")
```

I'm hoping to do something similar in SAS.  When I try

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="https://box.com/shared/static/<url>.xlsx"
        OUT=WORK.MYEXCEL
        DBMS=XLSX
        REPLACE;
RUN;
```

SAS tries to look for a document with the name "https://box.com/shared/static/.xlsx".

When I try

```
filename xlsxFile http "https://box.com/shared/static/<url>.xlsx";

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=xlsxFile
        OUT=WORK.MYEXCEL
        DBMS=XLSX
        REPLACE;
RUN;
```

I get

```
ERROR: This "filename URL" access method is not supported by "proc import". Please copy the file to local disk before running the 
       procedure.
```

Is there an easy way to have SAS access files from this type of URL?  I've checked these few threads:
https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/import-excel-file-from-the-web/td-p/134158
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Importing-XLSX-from-URL-Issue/td-p/446758
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/proc-import-xlsx-from-url/td-p/635834

And it seems like I may need to do some work to get SAS to create a file object from the URL but I don't quite understand how the code is working and when I naively try something similar:

```
filename xlsxFile http "https://box.com/shared/static/<url>.xlsx";

data file;
   n=-1;
   infile xlsxFile recfm=s nbyte=n length=len;
   input;
   file  "file_name.xlsx" recfm=n;
   put _infile_ $varying32767. len;
run;

PROC IMPORT OUT= input DATAFILE= "file_name.xlsx" 
     DBMS=xls REPLACE;
     SHEET="sheet_name";
     GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

I get the following error:

```
Spreadsheet isn't from Excel V5 or later.  Please open it in Excel and Save as V5 or later
Requested Input File Is Invalid
ERROR: Import unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
```

Any help would be appreciated.  The reason I'd like to do it this way is because the files at the static links are updated daily and I want to avoid having to copy files to the SAS server every day.  So if this won't work I am also interested in other work arounds that would accomplish the same thing.

I can obviously write a script that will fetch the updated files and write them to the server where SAS can access them as needed, but wanted to see if I could get this to work first.

Using the Box API from within SAS would also be another option if anyone has successfully gotten that to work.  As I mentioned I am new to SAS so trying to access the API seemed like it would be too difficult at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the URL actually downloads the file?  Two things to check.  One is download the file manually and try to get PROC IMPORT to read it. Perhaps the file is not really an XLSX file.  Also check the file you copied with the data step.  If it is an XLSX file then you should be able to read the individual files inside of it using the ZIP filename engine. In particular an XLSX file must contain a file name `xl/workbook.xml`.

Comment: This code has two additional things to try around copying. One is using PROC HTTP to copy the file instead of the URL filename engine.  The other is using the FCOPY() function to copy the file. You shouldn't need to use both.  https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2013/09/17/copy-file-macro/

Comment: proc http ending up solving the problem, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely need to download the file.  As Tom notes in comments, make sure to check this is really an xlsx file; but assuming  it is, some suggestions for dealing with it.

Copying it over by hand like you're doing is doable, and I'll put some code that works at the bottom of the answer, but it's way overkill nowadays - you're probably reading decade-old papers from before the modern day of SAS.  In particular, you should use PROC HTTP to GET the file, rather than using the URL directly - it's just much easier that way.

Another possibility is you could use python for this!  Regardless of your SAS setup, you can use python to script SAS, or use SAS to run Python, very easily nowadays.  SASPy project (on github) for SAS 9, or the SAS SWAT package (also on github I believe) for connecting to SAS Viya, lets you very easily talk back and forth with Python and SAS, even in production - I do it all the time.  And on top of *that*, you can even write SAS user-written functions *in python* now - so there're a bunch of ways to get your Python into SAS, if you want.  I am a SAS (primary) developer, but I use Python for web-related stuff, since it's just better at it.  See my [paper](https://github.com/snoopy369/presentations/blob/master/Python%20and%20SAS/Connecting%20to%20Datasets%20Through%20Python%20APIs%20and%20SASpy.pptx) for more details, or lots of other resources on the subject.

---

Assuming you just want to import the file and don't want to keep track of the excel file ultimately, you can just read it from a temp filename, which will clean itself up afterwards:

```
filename _httpin temp;

proc http method="get" 
  url="https://github.com/snoopy369/SASL/raw/master/Excel%20Precision.xlsx"
  out=_httpin;
run;

proc import file=_httpin out=test dbms=xlsx replace;
run;
```

If you want the excel file saved somewhere (sounds like you don't, but if you do), then instead of `temp` assign that httpin filename to a real location.

```
filename _httpin "c:\temp\whatever.xlsx";
```

If you really want to do that binary file copy business, do it this way:

```
filename _httpin temp;
filename _httpout "c:\temp\Excel Precision.xlsx";

proc http method="get" 
  url="https://github.com/snoopy369/SASL/raw/master/Excel%20Precision.xlsx"
  out=_httpin;
run;

data _null_;
  _in = fopen('_httpin','I',1,'B');
  _out= fopen('_httpout','O',1,'B');
  rec='20'x;
  do while (Fread(_in) eq 0);
    rc = fget(_in,rec,1);
    rc = fput(_out,rec);
    rc = fwrite(_out);
  end;
  rc = fclose(_in);
  rc = fclose(_out);
run;


proc import file=_httpout out=test dbms=xlsx replace;
run;
```

Comment: proc http worked! Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In hindsight it seems relatively obviously that proc http is what I needed.  One of the things I've been struggling with is searching for answers to my SAS questions online.  I'm used to google my error and finding a relevant stackoverflow thread, but when I google a SAS question it sends me to hard-to-parse official documentation or other old forums.  Do you have any good SAS resources that you usually go to?  Or advice on how to phrase questions or find relevant answers?  Thanks again!

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Other than StackOverflow, there is the sas forums (https://communities.sas.com), and the SAS-L Listserv if you want to go old school (sas-l@listerv.uga.edu), among quite a few other resources.

Comment: The challenge you'll find is that the "old" stuff is still in common use in a lot of places, SAS struggles to get people to update (even though the update is free) due to corporate reasons, so people are still using 9.2 (a version that came out in about 2007) and even older versions.  SAS official blog posts are often the best answer (like Tom's link to Chris Hemedinger's post), as they tend to only use "new" things.